# Let $K$ be a ring with unity. Prove that $K[X_1, \ldots, X_{m+1}]$ and $K[X_1, \ldots, X_{m}][X]$ are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

This is a lemma that authors Amann/Escher of textbook **Analysis I** consider *clear*.

> Let $K$ be a ring with unity. Then $K[X_1, \ldots, X_{m+1}]$ and $K[X_1, \ldots, X_{m}][X]$ are isomorphic.

I typed carefully authors' definitions of ring of formal power series and that of polynomials in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3211843/what-is-the-difference-between-kx-1-ldots-x-m-1-colorbluex-and).

**My attempt:**

> If $p \in K[X_1, \ldots, X_{m+1}]$ then $p$ is a function from $\Bbb N^{m+1}$ to $K$. If $p' \in K[X_1, \ldots, X_{m}][X]$ then $p'$ is a function from $\Bbb N$ to $K[X_1, \ldots, X_{m}]$.
>
> We define a function $\mathcal F:K[X_1, \ldots, X_{m+1}] \to K[X_1, \ldots, X_{m}][X]$ by $\mathcal F (p) = p'$.

At this point, I am stuck at *matching* which $p$  to which $p'$. Please shed me some light!

Comment: What would you do if your vision were not clouded by that French definition of functions from $\mathbb{N}^{m+1}$ to $K$? Wouldn't you gather together the terms with the same degree of $X_{m+1}$? Then do exactly that. Take into account that the degree of each variable in that definition is the corresponding coordinate of the input tuple.

Comment: Also, keep [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) into account when you are going to translate 'gathering terms' into the language of mapping degrees to coefficients.

Comment: Hi @logarithm, the authors use such definitions to develop theory of polynomial functions. I have no choice but to take on that approach. I hope that somebodys justify that lemma from the authors' definitions.

Comment: I know. I am telling you how to do it. There is nothing of substance involved, only a translation from one language to another. Gathering terms with the same degree of $X_{m+1}$ becomes currying the last variable of $p$.

Comment: Are you familiar with their [universal mapping property](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2800198/242), and the consequent [uniqueness?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2825412/242)

Comment: @BillDubuque I am actually not familiar with them. I am just exposed to some basic abstract algebra in preparation to learn mathematical analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a proof and posted it here. If your are interested, please help me verify it. Thank you for your dedicated help!

---

If $f \in K[X_1, \ldots, X_{m}][X]$ then $f$ is a function from $\Bbb N$ to $K[X_1, \ldots, X_{m}]$. If $h \in K[X_1, \ldots, X_{m+1}]$ then $h$ is a function from $\Bbb N^{m+1}$ to $K$.

We define a function $\mathcal F: K[X_1, \ldots, X_{m}][X] \to K[X_1, \ldots, X_{m+1}]$ by $\mathcal F (f) = h$ where $h(n_1,n_2,\dots,n_{m+1}) = f(n_1)(n_2,\dots,n_{m+1})$.

It is easy to verify that $\mathcal F$ is bijective. Let $f_1,f_2 \in K[X_1, \ldots, X_{m}][X]$ and $(n_1,n_2,\dots,n_{m+1}) \in \Bbb N^{m+1}$.

We have

$\begin{aligned} & \mathcal F (f_1 + f_2) (n_1,n_2,\dots,n_{m+1})\\
= &(f_1+f_2)(n_1)(n_2,\dots,n_{m+1}) \\ = & (f_1(n_1)+f_2(n_1))(n_2,\dots,n_{m+1})\\
= & f_1(n_1)(n_2,\dots,n_{m+1}) + f_2(n_1)(n_2,\dots,n_{m+1})\\
= & \mathcal F (f_1) + \mathcal F (f_2) \end{aligned}$

and

$\begin{aligned} & \mathcal F (f_1 \cdot f_2) (n_1,n_2,\dots,n_{m+1})\\
= & (f_1 \cdot f_2)(n_1)(n_2,\dots,n_{m+1}) \\ = & \left( \sum_{k \le n_1} (f_1(k) \cdot f_2(n_1-k)) \right) (n_2,\dots,n_{m+1})\\
= & \sum_{k \le n_1} ((f_1(k) \cdot f_2(n_1-k))(n_2,\dots,n_{m+1})) \\ = & \sum_{k \le n_1} \left( \sum_{\bar n \le (n_2,\dots,n_{m+1})} ( f_1(k)(\bar n) \cdot f_2(n_1-k)((n_2,\dots,n_{m+1}) -\bar n)) \right) \\
= & \sum_{k \le n_1} \sum_{\bar n \le (n_2,\dots,n_{m+1})} ( f_1(k)(\bar n) \cdot f_2(n_1-k)((n_2,\dots,n_{m+1}) -\bar n)) \\
= & \sum_{(p_1,\dots,p_{m+1}) \le (n_1,\dots,n_{m+1})} ( f_1(p_1)(p_2,\dots,p_{m+1}) \cdot f_2(n_1-p_1)((n_2,\dots,n_{m+1}) - (p_2,\dots,p_{m+1}))) \\ = & \sum_{(p_1,\dots,p_{m+1}) \le (n_1,\dots,n_{m+1})} ( f_1(p_1)(p_2,\dots,p_{m+1}) \cdot f_2(n_1-p_1)(n_2 -p_2,\dots,n_{m+1}-p_{m+1})) \\
= & \sum_{(p_1,\dots,p_{m+1}) \le (n_1,\dots,n_{m+1})} (\mathcal F(f_1)(p_1,\dots,p_{m+1}) \cdot \mathcal F(f_2) ((n_1,\dots,n_{m+1}) - (p_1,\dots,p_{m+1}))) \\
= & (\mathcal F(f_1) \cdot \mathcal F(f_2))(n_1,\dots,n_{m+1}) \end{aligned}$

As a result, $\mathcal F$ is an isomorphism.